# Проблема с компиляцией приложения в Visual studio 2015

Tags: c++-cli, visual-studio-2015

Создаю консольное CLR приложение, запускаю, получаю вот что

> Предупреждение    MSB8003 Could not find WindowsSDKDir variable from the
>   registry.  TargetFrameworkVersion or PlatformToolset may be set to an
>   invalid version number.   ConsoleApplication8 C:\Program
>   Files\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets  366

> Ошибка    TRK0005 не удалось обнаружить "rc.exe". Не удается найти
>   указанный файл.   ConsoleApplication8 c:\Users\Anatoly\documents\visual
>   studio 2015\Projects\ConsoleApplication8\ConsoleApplication8\TRACKER  1

Должна запускаться программа и выводить Hello world.

Помогите решить проблему или подскажите куда копать.

**UPD:**

При создании пустого CLR и добавлении файла main.cpp с кодом

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    return 0;
}
```

то же самое предупреждение при запуске и ошибка

> Ошибка    LNK1104 эх єфрхЄё  юЄъЁ√Є№ Їрщы
>   "uuid.lib"    FlightOperator  C:\Users\Anatoly\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\FlightOperator\FlightOperator\LINK  1

**UPD2**

Дома все нормально компилируется. Такая проблема только на работе. На работе студия 2015 enterprice, дома - community. На работе еще установлена 2013 студия, дома 2010. Походу происходят конфликты. Как их разрешить? Я не могу удалить на работе 2013 студию, она нужна.

Comment: Может быть поможет с англоязычного [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14372706/visual-studio-cant-build-due-to-rc-exe)

Comment: А проект билдиться?

Comment: @ВалентинЧикунов нет

Comment: @alexolut, не помогло. Правда, на rc.exe теперь не ругается. Осталась ошибка с *uuid.lib*

Comment: А разве этот код не должен в ref-классе находиться?

Comment: @Qwertiy, судя по всему нет, потому что когда я создаю новое консольное (не пустое) CLR приложение, все выглядит примерно так же, за исключением вывода Hello world